# Arquillian & Testcontainers: Invalid Oracle URL

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, testcontainers, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to embed a Database-Testcontainer in an existing arquillian-test with embedded-glassfish as a container. I'm using a JNDI-datasource defined in a `glassfish-resources.xml`- and a `persistence.xml`-File. That's why I'm trying to use the JDBC-Proxy-Driver from testcontainers, which should become active when using `jdbc:tc:XY` as a URL.

`glassfish-resources.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="MyDs" jndi-name="jdbc/myds"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="MyDs" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource">
        <property name="user" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:tc:oracle:thin:@localhost:55821:XE"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

But all I'm getting is: `java.sql.SQLException: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben`. By debugging I could verify that `ContainerDatabaseDriver` is registered in `DriverManager`, but it seems that this has no effect?

Any ideas?

Here's the full Stacktrace, maybe it's useful:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:520)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:926)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:488)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:570)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:562)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1727)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:110)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.embedded_3_1.GlassFishContainer.deploy(GlassFishContainer.java:193)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:151)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:232)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:212)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:163)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ExternalConnectionPool.startUp(ExternalConnectionPool.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:731)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:115)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:103)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1512)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:944)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:98)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.createResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:907)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:133)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.createResource(ConnectorAllocator.java:161)
    ... 146 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Ungültiger Oracle-URL angegeben
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:286)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:511)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:156)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:101)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:119)
    ... 147 more
```

Comment: I assume Testcontainers starts the Oracle-XE container and Arquillian especially embedded-glassfish container runs out-of-the box. If I'm right, try to expose Oracle's port and try to connect to it using original jdbc url. I mean jdbc url without `:tc`.

Comment: It works with a fixed port, I've already tested that. But that's not a really good idea for a CI-server.

Comment: The main problem is the database container is managed by Testcontainers but Glassfish is not. Testcontainers has an own principle to handle JDBC urls. So you have to make the Oracle-XE instance available for Glassfish. It's your choice you'll expose the port (even if it is a runtime generated port), put Glassfish into Docker environment or you'll use another stuff. e.g Arquillian Cube.

Comment: OK, i thought by registering the ContainerDatabaseDriver in DriverManager there would be some magic selecting this Driver by Arquillian.